# C# byte array to Image

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I need to create an Image from a Byte Array but I don't know how to do this. I tried to do it like this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
{
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

But there was always the message that the parameter `ms` is not valid.
The exact Exception message is:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

With this I am reading the Array from the database

```
byte[] bytes = ObjectToByteArray(reader["profilepicture"]);

private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

*Can anybody please help me with this problem?*

Comment: Well where did you get the byte array from? What data is in it?

Comment: What type is the ".FromStream" method expecting? What's the full exception message? Please be more clear in your questions.

Comment: The Byte Array is from an Image that was stored in a Database

Comment: The FromStream expects a stream

Comment: You need to return an Image type object.

Comment: FromStream will throw an exception if the stream doesn't contain valid image data. So *what* does the array contain? How did you load it from the database? Can you view the image if you save it to a file?

Comment: Most ASO.NET providers do *NOT* return blobs as arrays, they return a stream to the underlying data. How did you load the data?

Comment: BinaryFormatter is not capable of doing this correctly.  You **must** use Image.Save().  Note that you'll get a significantly larger byte[].  And beware of the bug in the code that reads the image, you must not use *using* since the stream needs to remain readable as long as the image is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)

Comment: That's almost identical to the OP's code. The problem is *not* the disposal of the MemoryStream